# dynamic iframe height depending on

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any javascript algo that i can used to check for a website page height and put it as height of the iframe to render the page

step 1 : check what is the height of the website , let say www.cnn.com.my 
step 2 : get the height , and put in  ? 
step 3: render the page in iframe with height 'pre-set'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because of the Same-Origin policy, you can only access the properties of a page from the same domain as the current page using JavaScript. Trying to access the properties of a page from another domain is known as cross-domain scripting and is prohibited by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

@cometta:check what is the height of the website> 
I am sorry. NO.